# Maximum Raspberry Pi 4 WiFi hotspot clients

Tags: raspbian, wireless, pi-4, hotspot

I have configured Raspberry Pi 4 as a WiFi hotspot with `hostapd` on Raspbian Buster. I connected 10 clients, no problem. I want to use it as a Free WiFi.
So, I concern to know how many clients could be connected without any essential problem?

I searched about this title but I got nothing. Additionally, the WLAN Hardware of the **Raspberry Pi 4 B** is `Broadcom BCM43455`.

Any experience?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ephemeral Thanks for the response. So, by default, the max number of connected clients is 255 which can be further to e.g 400 by changing the config file, right?

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry it's 2007 per default. `IEEE 802.11 has a limit of 2007
# different association IDs, so this number should not be larger than that.` : So yes you can !

Comment: @Ephemeral Alright, so, the value of `max_num_sta` can't be more than "2007".

Comment: @Ephemeral Yes, I can widen the number of connected clients by DHCP server or IP address subnet mask. I configured the IP address range to `/16`, which means "65534" client can be connected. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I have deleted my comments about dhcp because your question is for hostapd only

Comment: @Ephemeral I think it's important. Imagine I'll change hostapd.conf to `max_num_sta=500` and IP address range to `/24`. In this case, just "254" of clients can connect to the hotspot. (Android and iOS can't be connected but Windows or Linux client would be connected without any Layer-3 connection, though.)

Comment: `In this case, just "254" of clients can connect to the hotspot` sorry but no, in this case 500 STAs can get association and only 254 clients can get an IP addr

Comment: @Ephemeral Sorry, yes. I meant that but in a bad way.

Comment: WiFi is a shared medium. What are "*essential problems*" for you? Response time, transfer rate, etc.? What limits?

Comment: @Ingo Thank you for the response. Problems like you mentioned. Additionally, for example I had an experience like it with an AP, the number of associated clients reached "400" and suddenly SSID disappeared. I mean this kind of problems, unusual and unnormal.

Answer (score 2):

From the `hostapd.conf` file :

```
# Maximum number of stations allowed in station table. New stations will be
# rejected after the station table is full. IEEE 802.11 has a limit of 2007
# different association IDs, so this number should not be larger than that.
# (default: 2007) 

max_num_sta=255
```

Comment: Sorry, it helps me to configure RPi if the software sight is just important. I need some experimental information about this question because there is some limitation on hardware sight.

Comment: Sorry I don't know for the hardware side.

Comment: [BCM43455](https://www.cypress.com/file/298786/download)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a [related question on the RPi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50162/maximum-wi-fi-clients-on-pi-3-hotspot) the number appears to vary from less than 10 upwards - dependent upon firmware version/config? - see the [Raspberry Pi GitHUb issue on the matter](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3010). An alternative is to use a USB WiFi adapter.